# Pass data from view to controler

Tags: laravel

I am making a laravel app and I want to pass data to the controller from a view. I want to pass the id of a vehicle in order to get certain information for that car from another table.

desc.blade.php

```
{{link_to_action('Insur_DocController@index', "Insurances&Docs", $v->id, array('id'=>$v->id))}}
```

Insur_DocController@index

```
public function index()
    {
     $values = DB::select('select * from insur_docs where car_id=?', $id);
         return View::make('pages.insur_docs', array(
                    'values' => $values,
         ));
    }
```

Displays this error: `Undefined variable: id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a route:

```php
Route::get('car/{id}', 'Insur_DocController@index');
```

Your controller method must expect the $id:

```php
public function index($id)
{
    ...
}
```

Your select will not work this way, you could change it to:

```
$values = DB::table('insur_docs')->where('car_id', $id)->get();
```

And check if you got something:

```
dd($values);
```

This line of code will dump and die your script, so you can see the result of your query.

There is also an error in the link, which should be:

```
{{link_to_action('Insur_DocController@index', "Insurances&Docs", array('id'=>$v->id))}}
```

Comment: I tried Route::get('insur_docs/{id}', 'Insur_DocController@index');

Comment: On which line of code of what file? There are no arrays showing in the code you posted here!

Comment: public function index($id)
 {
  $values = DB::select('select * from insur_docs where car_id=?', $id);
         return View::make('pages.insur_docs', array(
                    'values' => $values,
         ));
 }

Comment: and now that's another error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\QueryException::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in /base/data/home/apps/s~national-test/1.375666329355340025/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 555 and defined

Comment: got it should be ('select * from insur_docs where car_id=?', array($id)) Now the problem is that it displays a blank page :/

Comment: You are at least missing a `->get()` on your query and you should also use DB::raw() if you are doing raw queries, so you better change to my version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52207/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-user3592644)